# How to create a new week number column starting from sunday from date values column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column "date" with values in MM/DD/YYYY format. How can I create a new column called weeks, with the week number, where week is starting from sunday and not monday.

For example:
[image]
I want it like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need more data, but I believe you could do something like this

```
df['Sale_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Sale_Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Week'] = df['Sale_Date'] + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
df['Week'] = df['Week'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

This will push all the dates forward one day and then get the week. So essentially when it reads the date it will read it as Monday for a Sundays date giving you the expected week. However, I recieved a different week number than you so I'm not sure if you are using a different week function that I am.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Sale_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Sale_Date)

df['Week'] = df.Sale_Date.dt.strftime('%U')

df

   ID  sale_amt  Sale_Date Week
0   1       100 2022-06-10   23
1   2       200 2022-06-05   23
2   3       250 2022-06-04   22
```